# How to setup dask clusters and client by submitting a job on an HPC system with SLURM?

Tags: python, dask, dask-distributed

I just tested out a `dask.distributed` workflow to process some data. The workflow is to request 1 cpu for some hours on which I can launch a jupyter notebook (the "client"), and then from this notebook I am using

```
cluster = SLURMCluster(cores=10,memory="100GB",processes=1,walltime="02:00:00")
cluster.scale(50)
client = Client(cluster)
```

to set up 50 clusters. My experience is that if the client dies (i.e. reaches the amount of time I requested), the clusters also die, hence I need to make sure the client and the clusters can have the same lifespan.

I am wondering is there a way to set up a number of dask clusters from bash command line, which takes inputs from normal `#SBATCH` directives:

```
#SBATCH --ntasks=500
#SBATCH --ntasks-per-node=25
#SBATCH --time=20:00:00
```

and then once these resources are allocated, then launch a python script like what I already have in the jupyter notebook to process data? This way, I can make sure all dask workers/clusters will have the same lifespan and that data processing is only started once I have all workers ready.

Thanks.

Comment: The answer is to use [dask-mpi](https://mpi.dask.org/en/latest/).